# AWS S3: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an AWS account with read/write permissions as shown below:
[image]

I'd like to make it so that an IAM user can download files from an S3 bucket but I'm getting access denied when executing `aws s3 sync s3://<bucket_name> .` I have tried various things, but not to avail. Some steps that I did:

1. Created a user called s3-full-access
2. Executed `aws configure` in my CLI and entered the generated access key id and secret access key for the above user
3. Created a bucket policy (shown below) that I'd hoped grants access for my user created in first step.

[image]

My bucket has a folder name AffectivaLogs in which files were being added anonymously by various users, and it seems like though the bucket is public, the folder inside it is not and I am not even able to make it public, and it leads to following error.

[image]

Following are the public access settings:

[image]

Update: I updated the bucket policy as follows, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you run `aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket/` with those credentials? Did you turn off S3 Block Public Access? (The two checkboxes in the _Manage public bucket policies for selected buckets_ section.)

Comment: It gave me the following output: "PRE AffectivaLogs/"

Comment: Yes, I turned them off. Updated the question to show the screenshot.

Answer (score 14):

To test the situation, I did the following:

- Created an **IAM User** with no attached policies
- Created an **Amazon S3 bucket**
- Turned off S3 block public access settings:

  - *Block new public bucket policies*
  - *Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies*
- Added a **Bucket Policy** granting `s3:*` access to the *contents* of the bucket for the IAM User

I then ran `aws s3 sync` and got `Access Denied`.

I then modified the policy to also permit *access to the bucket itself*:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/stack-user"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This worked.

**Bottom line:** Also add permissions to access the **bucket**, in addition to the **contents of the bucket**. (I suspect it is because `aws s3 sync` requires listing of bucket contents, in addition to accessing the objects themselves.)

Comment: did you check the box for the "Block new public bucket policies" as you mentioned above. sorry, it was a bit confusing.

Comment: I updated the `Resource` key to have values `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*` and               `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket`, but still same error

Comment: I updated the question with my latest policy, which doesn't work either.

Comment: The two options for "Block new public bucket policies" need to be turned _OFF_.

Comment: Well, something is clearly different to my above scenario. If you _remove_ the bucket policy, can you still run `aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket/`? If not, then this proves that the credentials you are using match the user in the policy. You might want to create a new IAM User and a new Bucket using my instructions above just to confirm that you get expected results, then compare to your existing bucket to figure out what is different.

Comment: Yes, these options are turned off as shown in the screenshot in question.

Comment: even after deleting the bucket policy, I got the output for `aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket/` as follows: `PRE AffectivaLogs/`

Comment: In that case, you have other permissions that are granting access to the bucket. Check in IAM whether that IAM User has an S3 policy. It doesn't explain why you can't sync, but something is a bit strange.

Comment: Yes, IAM has full access to S3 using the policy https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess$serviceLevelSummary

Comment: Well, in that case they don't need the Bucket Policy. In fact, if you wish to give permissions only to one user, it is better to grant access in IAM rather than create a Bucket Policy for a single user. I don't know what would be causing the _Access Denied_. You should experiment to discover what is happening, such as creating a new bucket and trying to sync to it.

Answer (score 9):

If you use KMS encryption enabled on bucket you should also add policy that allows you to decrypt data using KMS key.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the S3 policy with the required [principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountId:user/*
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountId:user/*
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you can create IAM policy and attached it to the role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In above policies, the Principal : arn should not have any /* on the end. This is the IAM user arn.